# Windows cannot be installed on this disk. The selected disk has an MBR partition table

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, gpt

I hope this is the right place to ask this question since it's an issue somewhere between Windows and Ubuntu.

I used to dual boot Windows 10 alongside Ubuntu.

All worked fine until Windows forced some update on me after which I was unable to boot my computer (this seems to be a somewhat common issue). After many hours of fiddling around, I was able to gain access to my Ubuntu partition again which is more crucial since I use it for work (Windows for gaming only). However, I am still unable to boot Windows. After everything else I tried didn't work I decided to just reinstall Windows. When trying to do so in the partition where Windows used to be, however, I'm hit with the error message: "Windows cannot be installed to this disk. The selected disk has an MBR partition table. On EFI systems, Windows can only be installed to GPT disks."
This problem remains after using `gdisk` to convert the partition table from `MBR` to `GPT`, and doing `partprobe`, `grub-install`, `grub-update`, etc.

I've also tried `boot-repair` several times (pastebin: https://pastebin.com/WVP8fNPQ ---- it warns that "The device '/dev/sdb1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS").

If that's at all relevant, both Ubuntu and Windows were/are installed on sdb, though this hasn't caused any issues before.

I'm grateful for any help.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron it is usually nicer to install windows first, so it does not mess with grub, but it is not required.

Comment: Have you tried to format the partition for windows to NTFS?  Make sure you have right partition.

Comment: @crip659 just did --- no luck i'm afraid.

Comment: How are you trying to reinstall?  If by USB would try another download and/or USB stick.  Windows is very picky when making a USB installer from Ubuntu.  Need woeUSB or mkUSB.

Comment: After read pastebin, think you need more help than from me.  Would use disks to check health of hard drives.  Superblock errors don't sound good.

Comment: You have new UEFI system, but both Windows & Ubuntu in the now 35 year old BIOS/MBR configuration. Since 2012 Microsoft has required vendors to install in UEFI/gpt boot mode. But Windows only installs in UEFI mode to gpt drives. Now would be a good time to convert all drives to gpt, and reinstall in UEFI boot mode. But conversion will erase drives, so good backups required to restore your data. You may be able to just fix Windows with chkdsk on all NTFS partitions & make sure Windows fast start up is off.